# Twitter events bind in iOS 9.1 (callbacks)

Tags: javascript, ios, twitter

I have a webpage where I'm tracking twitter events like tweet, follow etc. using Twitter javascript as documented [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events).

Since iOS 9.1 came out avery action (tweet, follow etc.) redirects the user to the Twitter app (if installed). This is a cool feature, but the problem is I cannot track events anymore as the javascript doesn't bind to the actions made in the app.

Anyone facing the same issue? Any workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A response from a Twitter staff pointed out this upcoming change:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/forthcoming-change-to-web-intent-events/54718